# css :before Pseudo-element not displaying background-image with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, pseudo-element

I'm starting to use the :before pseudo element to display logos before anchor text in a list.

I've followed Nicolas Gallagher's instructions, but the background images are not displaying in IE8.  Works in other browsers.  Anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

I've posted the example here:
http://vervedesignstudios.com/gb/testBefore.html

Here is the markup: 
Thanks in advance for your advice.

```
<style>

/* Pseudo-element cropping bit */
.iLst24 li a:before {
    content:""; 
    float:left; 
    width:24px; 
    height:24px; 
    margin:0 6px 0 0; 
    background-image:url("images/HomeSprite.png");
    }

.iLst24 .fb a:before {background-position:0 0;}
.iLst24 .tw a:before {background-position:0 -50px;}
.iLst24 .yt a:before {background-position:0 -100px;}

</style>


<div class="iLst24">
    <ul>
        <li class="fb"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="tw"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="yt"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">YouTube</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working completely fine for me in IE8, on your demo and in [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/7fSv6/)...

Comment: Thanks Wesley. IE was also set to compatibility mode, which I did not notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 has multiple issues with float and specific width/height values on  tags. Try adding a "zoom:1" to trigger haslayout and see if that helps.

Comment: OMG why are you still doing work in IE8 you poor thing @adaam